# Why is FileSystemWatcher getting an Invalid Directory error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, filesystemwatcher

I'm trying to use a FileSystemWatcher to see when the contents of a folder change.  The folder is on the C drive (which is the same drive that my windows installation is)

My code gives me a "The Directory 'C:\Crap\Watch' is invalid'.

```
    var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    watcher.Path = @"C:\Crap\Watch\";
```

I'm running Visual studio as an Administrator.  The 'C:\Crap' existed, but I just created the '\Watch' folder inside for this.  I changed the folder to a different hard disk, and it had no problems.

Is windows being extra protective of the windows install drive?  What else should I do?

Comment: Are you able to watch a path that doesn't exist?

Comment: So when you instantiate the `FileSystemWatcher` class, your folder `Watch` doesn't exist ? and then you created it ? That could explain the error. `FileSystemWatcher` requires a valid path.

Comment: the path existed before run time

Comment: Do not obfuscate the actual directory path you are using.  The file system redirector on a 64-bit version of Windows can cause surprises.  And of course post the code that actually created the subdirectory since that's the code that is most likely to be incorrect.

Comment: I created the subdirectory by right clicking and saying "new folder"  I'm just running some test code

Comment: More reasons to assume the file system redirector is the issue.

Comment: I was getting the error before I added the FileInfo.  I removed it from my question